# How to combine texts from left to right using GSAP

Tags: css, animation, gsap

I just want to ask how did the developer do the animation of his name combining together from right to left? I just want to implement it myself to enhance my css skills.

Seems like he used GSAP ScrollTrigger here if I'm not mistaken.

https://www.danielspatzek.com/degenesis

Comment: Check inspector on google chrome, there is 8 blocks like mask

Comment: The [ScrollTrigger docs](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/) and [demos](https://greensock.com/st-demos/) can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an incomplete jsFiddle that will hopefully point you in the right direction:
http://jsfiddle.net/86wkz3qu/19/

This example doesn't use scrollTrigger but I would highly recommend using it for something like this.

NOTE: Make sure the result display window is `870px` for this example to get this sort of thing to scale I would try using `vw` instead of `%`

Sorry I can't spend more time on this- but good luck! :)